# Shortcode for a link and thumbnail

Tags: images, shortcode, urls, id

```
<?php


// Add Shortcode
function blog_shortcode( $atts ) {

// Attributes
extract( shortcode_atts(
    array(
        'id' => '',
    ), $atts )
);

// Code
if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
    $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id( $id ) );
}
if ( isset( $id ) ) {
    return '<img src="' . $url . '"/><a href="' . get_permalink( $id ) . '">' . get_the_title( $id ) . '</a>';
}

}
add_shortcode( 'blog', 'blog_shortcode' );


?>
```

I'm trying to make a shortcode to where I can basically type [blog id="xxxxxx"] and I'll get a link and thumbnail. Right now I'm getting the link but the thumbnail isn't working. I don't think I fully understand how to get the thumbnail ID to become a url for the < img > tag. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning the attachment URL to your `$url` variable:

```
$url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id( $id ) );
```

then passing that same variable back to `wp_get_attachment_url`:

```
return '<img src="' . wp_get_attachment_url( $url ) . '"/><a href="' . get_permalink( $id ) . '">' . get_the_title( $id ) . '</a>';
```

You should simply output it instead:

```
return '<img src="' .$url . '"/><a href="' . get_permalink( $id ) . '">' . get_the_title( $id ) . '</a>';
```

EDIT:

You are missing the post ID from has_post_thumbnail. The following should work.

```
<?php
// Add Shortcode
function blog_shortcode( $atts ) {

// Attributes
    extract( shortcode_atts(
                    array(
                'id' => '',
                    ), $atts )
    );

// Code
    $image = '';
    if ( isset( $id ) ) {
        if ( has_post_thumbnail( $id ) ) {
            $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id( $id ) );
            $image = '<img src="' . $url . '"/>';
        }
        return $image . '<a href="' . get_permalink( $id ) . '">' . get_the_title( $id ) . '</a>';
    }
}

add_shortcode( 'blog', 'blog_shortcode' );
?>
```

Comment: I changed it to .$url. but it's still not working. It just replaces the wp_get_attachment_url right?

Comment: Please update your question with your new code

Comment: It has been updated now with the new code

Comment: I've updated my answer - give that a shot.